# How to express that at least 4 of 14 variables in linear programming are greater than 10?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

A restriction condition in linear programming/non-linear programming problem (function Maximize), t1, t2,..., t14, how to express that at least 4 of the variables are greater than 10?

Comment: There are 1001 ways of picking 4 of the 14 variables, so you could add a whole load of constraints `cons = Or @@ (And @@@ Map[# > 10 &, Subsets[variables, {4}], {2}])` but I'd imagine that would be a bit slow to solve (variables are t1...t14)

Comment: If your problem were sufficiently symmetrical in its coefficients, you could specify `t1>=t2>=t3>=t4>=10>=t5...`

Comment: You could get around this non-convexity by solving multiple linear programs. On each iteration, choose a random sample of four variables and generate the constraints that the four of them must be greater than 10, and solve the linear program . Since there are a very small number (1001) of `Subsets[variables,{4}]`, you could probably try every single one.

Comment: Yes, this method is feasible, but it is a bit complicated, especially when there are more samples and variables.

Answer (score 2):

That's is quite likely impossible (but depends on the other constraints). Linear programs have a convex polytope as feasible set because the set of feasible points is an intersection of half spaces and because intersections of convex sets are conves.

The feasible set that you describe is not convex. See here for a 3-dimensional example where we want at least two of the three variable to be greater or equal to 1:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 Or @@ (And @@ Thread[# >= 1] & /@ Subsets[{x, y, z}, {2}]),
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}
 ]
```

[image]

(The rounded edges in the plot are due to the low plot resolution. Actually, they ought to be hard edges.)

You see, clearly not convex. So you problem is by itself (very likely) not a linear programming problem.

But your feasible set can be written as a finite union of convex sets. In the example above it is just 3 sets, but as flinty pointed out, in your case it is `Binomial[14, 4] == 1001` sets. On each of the sets, you can formulate a linear program. You solve all these problems an in the end pick the smallest of the the solutions of these subproblems.

Comment: Can you explain the reason in detail? I don't know much about the relationship between graphs and linear programming solutions.

Comment: What exactly isn't clear? I plotted the feasible set of an analogous low-dimensional linear program in order to show you that the feasible set is not convex. I tried to show you that (unless you add further suitable contraints to cut off the nonconvexity), your problem cannot be formulated as a linear program.